# Passing NTLM Windows Credentials from one WebApi to another WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, ntlm, webapi

I have a WebApi for our product software that uses Windows authentication and a custom database based autorization for restricting resources.
I would like to write an external WebApi (customized for a particular customer) that also uses Windows authentiation and calls the first "product" WebApi for the authorization.

My idea was to simply pass the IPrincipal or IIdentity object that I can access in the ApiController's User property, but I cannot seem to do this.

Is there any way I can do this? I would like to use RestSharp if possible, but I always receive az Unauthorized response.

The code I've tried is the following:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://destinationServer/DestinationApi/api");
restClient.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
var restRequest = new RestRequest("Authentication", Method.GET);
var restResult = this.restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @auburg how posting *any* code would help with "work around NTLM one hop restriction without usual Kerberos answer" post?

Comment: So what code of yours is receiving an unauthorized response ?

Comment: I've added the code snippet.

Comment: Nobody? Nothing? This does not seem to be a so rare scenario to me, yet I can't seem to find a solution.